# Set start day of the week in jQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking through the docs for the jQuery UI Datepicker (http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), but I can't find how to set the first day of the week as Monday.

Applying regional settings will set Monday as first day of the week, but this will also change the language.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try the firstDay option (in the options tab):

```
//getter
var firstDay = $('.selector').datepicker('option', 'firstDay');
//setter
$('.selector').datepicker('option', 'firstDay', 1);
```

Answer (score 82):

Here is an example config I use. Look at the last line with "firstDay: 1". 
I think using sytax like this to specify datepicker options looks better ;)

```
$('#datepickerfield').datepicker({
    constrainInput: true,   // prevent letters in the input field
    minDate: new Date(),    // prevent selection of date older than today
    showOn: 'button',       // Show a button next to the text-field
    autoSize: true,         // automatically resize the input field 
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',  // Date Format used
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,     // Disable selection of weekends
    firstDay: 1 // Start with Monday
})
```

Answer (score 10):

for using first day as monday :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#date_id" ).datepicker({ firstDay: 1 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by creating your own localization file for your language along with your own settings. See this page for details: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/Localization

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
                startDate: moment(),
                endDate: moment(),
                autoApply: true,
                locale: {
                    firstDay: 1
                },
                ranges: {
                    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                    'Last Week': [moment().startOf('isoWeek').subtract(7, 'days'), moment().endOf('isoWeek')
                        .subtract(7, 'days')
                    ]
                }
            }, cb);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
    function getFirstDateOfThisWeek(d)
    {
        var TempDate = new Date(d || new Date());            
        TempDate.setDate(TempDate.getDate() + (@Config.WeekStartOn - 1 - TempDate.getDay() - 7) % 7);           
        return TempDate;

    }

    var StartDate = getFirstDateOfThisWeek(new Date()); //1st date of this week
```