# Jquery UI Datepicker Widget change in Date format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery UI datepicker in one of my page, as a default setting it shows  calender starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday. Can I change this? I want it to be like  starting on Monday and ending on Sunday. Is it possible?
My code is like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8NH6/)

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

      $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set start day of the week in jQuery UI Datepicker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313317/set-start-day-of-the-week-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting [`firstDay`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-firstDay)  property

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( {firstDay: 1});        
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/X8NH6/2/)