# PhpMyAdmin, how to set 1st day for calendar

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Since version 5.1.3, there's no function PMA_addDatepicker in js/functions.js, so that I can set the 1st day for the calendar to Monday instead of Sunday.

I used to change this manually everytime I upgrade PMA.
How could I achieve this from now on?

Comment: Doesn't it use jQuery UI's datepicker? If so, you can change the starting day of the week: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313317/set-start-day-of-the-week-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: Hum, Im not aware of such configuration. I can have several datepickers is it? where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that this is now a parameter in config, also remember that it was a feature request from me about 3 years ago, cool!!

$cfg['FirstDayOfCalendar'] = 1; // 0 for sunday, 1 for monday