Date pickers should start on Monday instead of Sunday
I have a custom widget for date input:
class JQueryUIDatepickerWidget(DateInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(
            attrs={
                "size": 10,
                "class": "datepicker",
                "autocomplete": "off",
                "placeholder": "Select date",
            },
            **kwargs,
        )

but when I open date picker, it starts from Sunday, like: Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa.
Can I update it to start on Monday? Might it be solved adding some JS or JQuery code to my base.html


This is not a django-specific answer/question, more related to how you initialize the datepicker in JS. Here is a solution that looks to do what you are after, i.e. setting the firstDay: 1 https://stackoverflow.com/a/4016534/8382028
